# Download Ubuntu Minimal ISO 22.04LTS?

Tags: iso, 22.04

Are there any plans to make the ISO available for this version?

Thanks.

Comment: How minimal are you looking for? Ubuntu Server is not particularly heavy and will allow you to build with just the packages you want 

Comment: No I don't think so. It is possible to use the 20.04 mini.iso and do-release-upgrade. It is also possible to use the current Ubuntu Server 22.04  iso file to make a minimal system (and you can install some light-weight window manager or desktop environment if you wish).

Comment: @sudodus I confirm it worked for me, although the Ubuntu Server version adds some packages related to servers, so I'd use the mini.iso and do an upgrade

Answer (score 5):

No.

It was never supported by either Ubuntu nor Canonical.

It was produced as a by-product of a no-longer run procedure, as you'll note here

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

> Canonical and the Ubuntu project never officially supported the mini.iso ; it was produced as a by-product of building the debian-installer. As the Ubuntu Server image now uses `subiquity`, the build process that built mini.iso is no longer used, thus why this installation media is now old.

Comment: do you know if the new installer finally supports serial terminal installations? at the time of 20.04 the new installer REQUIRED a display output and would crash (well, would only say something like "initializing initramfs" FOREVER) when only presented with a serial terminal output, and the only way to install 20.04 over a terminal was to use the "not supported mini.iso"

Comment: No I don't, nor do I know if anyone has QA tested for it, discovered it works/doesn't (*thus filed a bug if it didn't; ie. regression over prior install prior six month cycle*) causing a decision to be made whether or not it will be supported. The installer has been around for years now though. Personally I only QA test *amd64* & almost exclusively desktop (server installs are only to subsequently test desktop post-installs so I always have screen+keyboard); I'm not involved with server QA.