# Where to find/create a "minimal" / network Ubuntu ISO? (Jammy; 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, iso, ubuntu-minimal, minimal-install

The Jammy desktop iso is > `4GB`.

I need a minimal iso.

The `Network installer` option is still featured for some reason in Alternative downloads: https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

> The network installer lets you install Ubuntu over a network. It includes the minimal set of packages needed to start and the rest of the packages are downloaded over the network. Since only current packages are downloaded, there is no need to upgrade packages immediately after installation.
>
> ...
>
> For 22.04 LTS, users can use the new Ubuntu Live installer to setup and configure a network install.

Ubuntu/Canonical updated the link to point, not to the "Network installer" that one might expect, but instead a discourse thread that adds nothing beyond what was already clearly stated in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#Status_of_the_Minimal_ISO_image.

[image: There is no network installer]

I can understand that the "minimal" iso was never anything more than an expedient for buntu devs, and also empathize with the phenomenon of users coming to depend on anything that is a transient hack, however forewarned and discouraged.

But `4.6gb` for a buntu image is considerably larger and excessively bloated beyond my needs, and I need a minimal iso (essentially ubuntu_desktop + `<desktop>` & drivers).

Is there anything like the former "minimal" images for jammy and newer that are built and hosted somewhere?
I'm okay with unofficial or community/contrib built images.

If not, where would I start to make my own "minimal" image?

---

Helpful links for duplicate flagging:

- [Create a custom ISO Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418328/create-a-custom-iso-ubuntu-22-04)
- [How to do a minimal install of 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264128/how-to-do-a-minimal-install-of-20-04)
- [Download Ubuntu Minimal ISO 22.04LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406736/download-ubuntu-minimal-iso-22-04lts)
- [Where is the MinimalCd / mini.iso for Groovy Gorilla?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291913/where-is-the-minimalcd-mini-iso-for-groovy-gorilla)
- [Is there any modern-day replacement for the Ubuntu Mini ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390215/is-there-any-modern-day-replacement-for-the-ubuntu-mini-iso)

Comment: The minimal install option is part of the installer itself and no longer an ISO itself. The size of the ISO is not an issue you should be concerned with: you need an 4Gb USB stock. Those are common.  The ISO itself contains software for ALL of us not just for you. The way to go: pick the normal ISO,install, pick the minimal option and when done. create a txt file with all you alterations and execute it to remove all you want to remove. That method is future proof too: in 1/2 a year it will also work for that release.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there anything like the former "minimal" images for jammy and newer that are built and hosted somewhere?*

No, for the reasons you explained yourself in your question.

The only supported Ubuntu Minimal/Network installer for 20.04 and newer is the option you pointed to in your question.